# Conditionally render different img src in Vue depending on screen size?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm in the process of learning Vue and the last thing I'm stuck on for a Frontend Mentor project is to change the src of an img depending on if it's mobile or desktop.

I'm assuming I need to conditionally render it, I'm just not sure how with Vue.

```
<script setup>
  import Main from "./components/Main.vue"; 

  const imgSrc = //Ternary here?
</script>

<template>
 <img class="absolute z-10 inset-x-0 top-0 w-full object-cover max-h-60 md:h-60"
 :src="imgSrc"
 />
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you don't know how to verify the user device

```js
let imgSrc
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    imgSrc = 'mobile.png'
} else {
    imgSrc = 'pc.png'
}
```